# Can I exit firebase service once I have my own server?

Tags: firebase, server, payment-gateway, backend

I am developing a new app which has to scale higher user base . Which is better firebase or building my own backend services ? 
Does firebase support quick online payment services ?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: )There's no way to answer that question without understanding your use case. Besides that it's not an appropriate question for the site. Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcv)